# GOTO is unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file, goto

As part of my login script for the company I work for I am trying to create this script that I copied from one of our other sites. But when I run the script to test I get the "GOTO Was unexpected at this time" and the script stops. Any one have advice? Mind you the script does not contain the line spaces seen in the post.

```
echo ################################# MAPPING E DRIVE #######################################

:NEXT
REM MAP This section maps E: drive

REM to file://fwlfp003/Data_Engineering for Engineering Users

%logonserver%\netlogon\ifmember "******\FWL-Data_Engineering_A" or "***\FWL-Data_Engineering_R"

IF NOT errorlevel 1 GOTO NEXT

echo Mapping Network Drive E \\FWLFP003\Data_Engineering

net use E: \\FWLFP003\Data_Engineering /PERSISTENT:NO
```

EDIT****

Ok so I found the culprit.

```
IF NOT errorlevel 1 GOTO NEXT
```

Should state

```
IF NOT==errorlevel 1 GOTO NEXT
```

Ifmember is an application that checks against a users group membership, if it returns with those groups the drive is then mapped. If the user is not in the group it returns a "1" and checks the next line for group member ship. I wonder if I can check all groups at once instead of calling the app multiple times throughout the script. Any Ideas?

Comment: looks like you will have an infinite loop there if its not an engineering user. If ifmember returns somethign other than 1 ( i assum indicating its not an engineering user) the goto would jump to the :NEXT label and would then retry ifmember again, and again ..... Should the :NEXT be after the net use command?

Comment: What is `%logonserver%\netlogon\ifmember` ? If it is a batch file, then you'd need `call %logon...` else execution is transferred to `ifmember`. The parameters to `ifmember`seem strange. There appears to be nothing wrong with the only GOTO you have in the list you give us, so I suspect that the report is actually being generated by `ifmember`. What do you mean by `the script stops?` do you mean that it terminates and returns to the prompt or that it hangs? By 'line spaces' do you mean 'blank lines?'

Comment: instead of doing edits, you should have posted regular answer to own question and accept it when SO allows

Comment: After reading `help if` I have no idea why your solution should be a real solution. I can't make it work on my machine like this.

Comment: No, that cannot be the fix. `if not errorlevel 1 ...`, `if not==errorlevel 1 ...`, and `if not; =,errorlevel 1 ...` are all equivalent and valid. That is because the `=` `;` and `,` are all token delimiters that function the same as a space in this context. Your original IF statement is correct. The error must have been someplace else.